# Installation : using yum install kubeadm kubectl kubelet am getting below error

Tags: kubernetes

failure: repodata/repomd.xml from kubernetes: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/kubernetes-el7-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml signature could not be verified for kubernetes

anyone please help.

Answer (score -1):

Your `kubernetes.repo` is probably outdated or using a deprecated mirror. Can you share your output from the following :

- `ll /etc/yum.repos.d`
- `cat /etc/yum.repos.d/kubernetes.repo`

You could refer [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/37922) answer as well, might be helpful.